# How do I position a set of slides to each other using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a carousel on a project website page using pure vanilla javascript. I am trying to position the slides before adding the event listeners on the buttons but it does not seem to work.

This is the HTML

```js
const carousel = document.querySelector('.container-items');
const slides = [...carousel.children];
const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.leftbtn');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.rightbtn');

//Position slides next to each other
function positionSlides(slides){
for (let index = 0; index < slides.length; index++) {
  slides[index].style.left = slideWidth * index+ 'px';
  
}
}
positionSlides(slides);
```

```css
.explore-section__container{
  position: relative;
}
.explore-section__container-items{
 position: relative;
}
.container-items{
  list-style: none;

}

.explore-image{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  top: 10%;
}
.btn{
  position: absolute;
  
}
.leftbtn{
  left:  38%;
  
}
.rightbtn{
  right: 38%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "explore-section__container">
  <div class = "explore-section__container-items">
    <button class = "btn leftbtn">leftbtn</button>
    <ul class = "container-items">
      <li>
      <img class = "explore-image active" src="images/conference.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class = "explore-image" src="images/food.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class = "explore-image" src="images/gym.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button class = "btn rightbtn">rightbtn</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have not written the code for the event listeners yet. I want to get the elements first positioned next to each other.

Comment: I was trying to make the image circular. The carousel on the website I am rebuilding is circular.

Comment: I was trying to make the image circular. The carousel on the website I am rebuilding is circular.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this using javascript, its a CSS/HTML thing, javascript role in such an thing would be to slide and animate the `<li>` HTML tags, there is many ways to implement what you want, here is an example:

```css
.explore-section__container{
  position: relative;
}
.explore-section__container-items{
 position: relative;
}
.container-items{
  list-style: none;
  width: 480px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-items li {
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 width: 150px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.explore-image{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
}
.btn{
  float:left;
  margin: 60px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "explore-section__container">
  <div class = "explore-section__container-items">
    <button class = "btn leftbtn"><</button>
    <ul class = "container-items">
      <li>
      <img class = "explore-image active" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class = "explore-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class = "explore-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="">
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button class = "btn rightbtn">></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know about inline block but I am trying to create a carousel in that when you click on the button it slides to another picture. I was able to do this using the exact steps I used on an image slider application but it doesn't seem to work for my project.